# Concept of "sawab" according to Quran and hadith

Tags: quran, hadith, source-identification

I have been told that sawab is a unit of "naiki". It will be something that will be counted or weighed on the Judgement Day. Is this concept supported by Quran and hadith? Specifically, as a unit of measuring good deeds.

If not, what is the concept of "sawab" according to Quran and hadith?

Based on my [search in quran](http://quran.com/search?q=%D8%AB%D9%88%D8%A7%D8%A8), it is used in meaning of "reward" or "recompense", which can be both good or [bad](http://quran.com/83/36)

Comment: In quran and hadith there are several compares between sawabs.but there is no unit or minimum sawab to go to haven.if there is one,many people will sure about their other world and next start to do bad things.

Answer (score 1):

**The main meaning of the word Sawab(thawab) in origin is referral and recurrence.**

**The significant point is that the word Thawab has repeated 13 times in the holy Quran, and seemingly all of them have the same meaning, actually their meanings are: the reward of good deeds**

To see the complete matter regarding the meaning of thawa, you can refer to the following references.

---

***Reference(s):***

- [www.porseshkadeh.com](http://www.porseshkadeh.com/Question/38898/)
- [www.encyclopaediaislamica.com](https://web.archive.org/web/20130930195931/http://www.encyclopaediaislamica.com/madkhal2.php?sid=4283) (Wayback archived link)

Comment: Do you have english references? I don't know persian. or can you translate the relevant portions from the links

Comment: @Goto, I solely mention the main meaning of it which means:
 
The reward of the good deed. The significant point is that the word Thawab has repeated 13 times in the holy Quran, and seemingly all of them have the same meaning, actually their meanings are: the reward of good deeds. (in accordance with the following site):

http://www.encyclopaediaislamica.com/madkhal2.php?sid=4283

Comment: so it is not a unit of good deeds?

Comment: I reckon its precise meanings is "reward" which is related to good deeds. tis my opinion buddy. (that I assume it could be a true definition of it according to some definitions..)

Comment: @goto have u played snooker? 'naiki' or 'thawab' is something like that, 1 deed has more points than the other... all these add up and weigh in the [balance](http://quran.com/101)

Answer (score 0):

It is the satisfaction of doing good the self reward of being in service to Allah! If one does good for thawab or reward from Allah than that is doing business and not doing good for the sake of good! Service to humanity is piety in itself and must come from being good and not for reward!